# Header of NavigationView not showing unless there is margin to top

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am creating an Android app which got a navigation drawer in a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_select_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_options" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the `navigation_drawer_header_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButtonCloseDrawer"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="X"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The header layout is added but not showing unless I add either a top margin for the TextView or some padding to the RelativeLayout which pushes the TextView down.

Why won't it show as defined in the header layout? Why is the need to push the layout in order for it to be shown?

Comment: what is the version of android that you run the app?

Comment: And can you add na image with navigation drower open?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Im trying to run on android 5.1.1. I have added an image view with a large image and the same thing happens.. I can only see the lower half of the image since the upper half is hidden. This also made me realize that its hidden behind a toolbar I've added manually

Comment: try check if is hidden behind toolbar by make toolbar visibility gone. And you are adding toolbar inside drower layout?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you made me realize the issue was with the toolbar and that the issue was already solved in another question. If you want, you can summarize the answer with a link to the original question and I will accept your answer. The original question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826829/display-content-under-toolbar

Comment: So I sumarize the answer with the link acept answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As understood from the comments, you got a `ToolBar` which hides the content instead of staying above it at all times. Check out this answer here which might solve your problem:

[Display content under toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826829/display-content-under-toolbar)